# How to use $(this) on AJAX success?

Tags: jquery, ajax, sweetalert

There are buttons in the each rows of the table. When user click it, a sweetalert is fired to display confirmation window. If user click yes, then an AJAX is executed to post the row values.

The post process is working, but I am unable to change the button attribute and a label text after AJAX success call. This is my script.

```
$("#tbl_list_pemenuhan tbody").on('click','.btn_memo', function() {                 

    var no_penuh    = $(this).closest('tr').find("td:eq(1)").text();
    var no_minta    = $(this).closest('tr').find("td:eq(2)").text();

    var data        = 'no_pnh='+no_penuh+'&no_mnt='+no_minta;


    swal({
        title               : "Apa anda yakin?",
        type                : "warning",
        showCancelButton    : true,
        confirmButtonColor  : "#0C0",
        confirmButtonText   : "Ya!",
        cancelButtonText    : "Batal",
        closeOnConfirm      : true
    },function(){

        var elem = $(this);

        $.ajax({
            type    : "POST",
            url     : "<?php echo site_url('con_atk/buat_memo_direct'); ?>",                        
            data    : data,                     
            success : function(data){   
                elem.attr('disabled','disabled');
                elem.closest('tr').find('label').text('SENT');

                alert("SUCCESS");
            }
        });             
    });     
});
```

note:
in the AJAX success, the alert is executed but not the `elem`

Comment: Define `var elem = $(this);` outside the `function`, or `bind` `this` at the end of the `function() { ... }.bind(this)`. Functions declared the way you did have their own `this`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Cause of the problem

Functions declared the way you did have their own `this`, so using `$(this)` no longer gets you the element that triggered the event.

### Solution 1

Define `var elem = $(this);` outside the inner `function()` (the one containing the ajax call).

### Solution 2

`bind` `this` at the end of the `function() { ... }.bind(this)`.

### Solution 3 (ES6)

Arrow functions do not have their own `this` so replacing `function()` by `()=>` also does the job, but will only work if you run it in an ES6 capable browser (or if you're using a transpiler like Babel).

Answer (score 0):

You can also get the event object:

```
$("#tbl_list_pemenuhan tbody").on('click','.btn_memo', function(event) {
```

Then use that:

```
var elem = $(event.target);
```

Comment: I'd recommend not to use generic terms (which might potentially be or become reserved terms) as variable names. Also the reference to the element is already there thanks to jQuery using `$(this)`.

Comment: There is always scope for a doubt to the reader whether the $(this) is tbody instance or btn_memo instance. I think this makes it more clear. And as for the `elem` variable name, I agree with you, its just OP's choice of variable name :)

Comment: I was talking about your variable naming `event`.